# Rails Update to 3.2.11 breaks running multiple servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

Our application runs two Rails servers at different ports that talk to each other. Using Rails 3.2.8, I could open a terminal, `cd` to the project, run `rails s -p3000`, open another terminal, run `rails s -p3001` and everything worked fine. The gemfile contains `thin`, so `thin` would be launched automatically, but using the `rails s` would allow using the `--debugger` when needed.

Since updating the Rails 3.2.11 this no longer works. I get an error: "A server is already running. Check /home/george/Projects/dashboard/tmp/pids/server.pid". I can launch `thin` directly on both ports, but then have no debugging support. Launching `thin` on one and `rails` on the other seemed to not work, but it was not clear that all the server tasks were getting killed when the error stopped the server.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Both commands are checking the default PID file location (`tmp/pids/server.pid`), so you're seeing this error. Try running multiple servers like so:

**Server 1:** `bundle exec rails s`

**Server 2:** `bundle exec rails s -p 3001 -P tmp/pids/server2.pid`

Comment: I'll have to try that. I assumed something like that would be the correct fix, but could not find it documented anywhere. Where is the documentation for the -P flag?

Comment: I found that via `bundle exec rails s --help`.

Comment: Ahhh..., need that 's'. Thanks, you get credit for the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Posted elsewhere on Stackoverflow was the mention that if you have problems with rails 3.2.11, try locking `rack` at 1.4.1. This seems to work so far. I added:

```
gem 'rack' , '1.4.1'
```

to the `gemfile`, and then executed

```
bundle update rack
```

Answer (score 0):

try using foreman https://github.com/ddollar/foreman

Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/281-foreman?view=comments