# Server is already running in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, command-prompt, webrick

When I am starting rails server using `rails s` command it is showing `A server is already running. Check C:/Sites/folder/Pids/Server.pids`

When I open the file it is outputting a 4 digit number only so how could I resolve this issue ?

**FYI**

1. No other instance of Rails cmd is running this time.
2. Checked Task manager but only `cmd.exe` is showing no else process is running. (using Windows).

Comment: I remover server.pid from \tmp\pids

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Remove the file: C:/Sites/folder/Pids/Server.pids

*Explanation*
In UNIX land at least we usually track the process id (pid) in a file like server.pid. I think this is doing the same thing here. That file was probably left over from a crash.

Comment: what exactly this file do and cause for this ..can you please explain it a little more :)

Comment: Sorry, I should have commented further. In UNIX land at least we usually track the process id (pid) in a file like server.pid. I think this is doing the same thing here. That file was probably left over from a crash.

Comment: I think I clone it from Git so do u think it might be a cause ? https://github.com/swapnesh/Add_twitter_bootstrap

Comment: After doing this I'm still getting a "Port in use" for 3000.  Anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Run `netstat -a -o` at a command prompt to see what process is using port 3000

Comment: causes socket.rb:206:in `bind': Address already in use - bind(2) for 0.0.0.0:3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE), check joshs answer how to resolve this after removing .pid

Comment: its `/tmp/pids` now

Answer (score 262):

**TL;DR Just Run this command to Kill it**

```
sudo kill -9 $(lsof -i :3000 -t)
```

**Root Cause:**
Because PID is locked in a file and web server thinks that if that file exists then it means it is already running. Normally when a web server is closed that file is deleted, but in some cases, proper deletion doesn't happen so you have to remove the file manually
**New Solutions**

when you run **rails s**

=> Booting WEBrick

=> Rails 4.0.4 application starting in development on `http://0.0.0.0:3000`

=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options

=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server

**A server is already running. Check /your_project_path/tmp/pids/server.pid.**
Exiting

So place your path shown here /your_project_path/tmp/pids/server.pid

and remove this **server.pid** file:

```
rm /your_project_path/tmp/pids/server.pid
```

**OR Incase you're server was detached then follow below guidelines:**

If you detached you rails server by using command "rails -d" then,

Remove rails detached server by using command

```
ps -aef | grep rails
```

**OR by this command**

```
sudo lsof -wni tcp:3000
```

then

```
kill -9 pID
```

**OR use this command**

To find and kill process by port name on which that program is running. For 3000 replace port on which your program is running.

```
sudo kill -9 $(lsof -i :3000 -t)
```

**Old Solution:**

```
rails s -p 4000 -P tmp/pids/server2.pid
```

Also you can find this post for more options
[Rails Update to 3.2.11 breaks running multiple servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329370/rails-update-to-3-2-11-breaks-running-multiple-servers)

Comment: because PID is locked in file and web server thinks that if that file exists then it means it is already running. Normally when web server is closed that file is deleted, but in some cases proper deletion don't happen so you have to remove file manually

Comment: Careful this will also kill your browser if it's pointing to :3000!

Comment: perfect solution for `sudo kill -9 $(lsof -i :3000 -t)`

Comment: Very nice! I created a function on my bash profile that kill the running server using this command, so you just type `kill_server` on the terminal and everything is done. I declared this on my bash profile: `kill_server() { sudo kill -9 $(lsof -i :3000 -t) }`

Answer (score 88):

```
lsof -wni tcp:3000
```

Then you should see the ruby process and you can run

```
kill -9 processid
```

you should be good to run the process now

```
rails s thin
```

running multiple processes doesn't seem like a good idea and from what i've read many people agree. I've noticed many memory leaks with rails unfortunately so I couldn't imagine having two processes running. I know with one overtime my page refreshes increasingly become slower because of the data being stored on memory.

Answer (score 30):

```
kill -9 $(lsof -i tcp:3000 -t)
```

Comment: @CalamityAdam Rails usually runs on port 3000. He searches for processes based on that and gets only the PID from them (`-t` option) and then kills the process by that retrieved PID.

Answer (score 15):

You can get rid of the process by killing it:

```
kill -9 $(lsof -i tcp:3000 -t)
```

Comment: I like this one. Nice and concise, yet complete. Cheers.

Answer (score 12):

```
$ lsof -wni tcp:3000

# Kill the running process
$ kill -9 5946

$ rm tmp/server.pids
```

foreman start etc start the service

Answer (score 7):

`gem install shutup`

then go in the current folder of your rails project and run

`shutup` # this will kill the Rails process currently running

You can use the command 'shutup' every time you want

DICLAIMER: I am the creator of this gem

NOTE: if you are using rvm install the gem globally

```
rvm @global do gem install shutup
```

Answer (score 5):

It happens when you kill your server process and the pid file was not updated.
The best solution is to delete the file **Server.pid**.

Use the command

> `rm <path to file Server.pid>`

Answer (score 4):

On Windows Rails 5.2, delete this file

```
c:/Sites/<your_folder>/tmp/pids/server.pid
```

and run

```
rails s
```

again.

Answer (score 4):

> Just open that C:/Sites/folder/Pids/Server.pids and copy that 4 digit
> value.that 4 digit value is nothing but a PID, which you need to kill
> to stop the already running process.

*then to stop the process use below command*

```
 kill -9 <pid>
```

once that already running process get stopped then hit

`rails s` to start the rails server

Answer (score 3):

Probably you suspended the server by: `^Z`.

The four digital number that `vim C:/Sites/folder/Pids/Server.pids`outputs is the process id.

You should `kill -9 processid`, replacing the process id with the 4 numbers that vim (or other editor) outputed.

Comment: What's the right way to stop the server properly? CTRL + C?

Answer (score 3):

Run:

in Ubuntu/linux

```
 sudo rm /var/www/html/rails/WBPOCTEST/tmp/pids/server.pid
```

Or

```
 pkill -9 ruby
```

or

```
lsof -wni tcp:3000

kill -9 pid
```

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu :-
`sudo kill -9 $(lsof -i :3000 -t)`

where,
`3000 is port number`

Works for me....

For older versions :-

`rails s -p 3000 -P tmp/pids/server2.pid`

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows, you just need to do only one step as    ***'rails restart'***  and then again type 
***'rails s'*** 
You are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

**Run:** `fuser -k -n tcp 3000`

This will kill the process running at the default port 3000.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and tried setting it to a different port, but the only thing I needed to do was to delete my `[app_directory]/tmp/pids/server.pid` and everything was good to go.

Answer (score 0):

my docker container has no `lsof`. Try `sudo kill -9 $(netstat -ano -p tcp | grep :3000 | awk '{ print $7 }' | grep -Po '^[\d]+')`

Answer (score 0):

I have face this issue in my rails application when i used docker in windows mechine.
i just removed the `server.pid` file from the project and restart the rails application.

You just need to delete `C:/Sites/folder/Pids/Server.pid` this file

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the TMP folder in your application.
Go to the pids folder and delete the files present. Now rerun the server. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was after a way I could intuitively understand (as opposed to just memorise).

#### All you need to know is two things

1. Run the `ps` command to list processes, and
2. Run the `kill` command to stop a process

---

#### Example

Then it's as simple as:

```
ps
# PID TTY           TIME CMD
# 32953 ttys000    0:00.71 -zsh
# 33730 ttys001    0:00.67 -zsh  
# 46844 ttys004    0:01.78 puma 4.3.12 (tcp://localhost:3000) [myapp]
```

look for the PID that matches your rails server, and pass it to `kill`

```bash
kill -9 46844
```

Run `ps` again to see that it's now stopped.

#### Note

- For more info on `-9`, run `man kill`.

Answer (score 0):

> A server is already running. Check C:/Sites/folder/Pids/Server.pids

Remove the `server.pids` file from the directory. Then try starting your rails server again from your terminal.

---

In the event if the above (deleting the `server.pids` file) still does not work, try this [link](https://web-crunch.com/posts/address-already-in-use-resolving-the-bind-error-in-ruby-on-rails). This article shows you if you are still getting the `"Address already in use - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)"` error when starting `rails -s`.