# Deleted Server.pids but still can not run app in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After deleting the file Server.pids as instructed in the below link, I still can not run my app. Please see at the end of this message the output in terminal.
How can I solve this?

Thanks

Link:
[Server is already running in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072846/server-is-already-running-in-rails)

New error in terminal (Mac):
Exiting
/Users/agustinguerrero/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/socket.rb:206:in `bind': Address already in use - bind(2) for 0.0.0.0:3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

Comment: open your taskmanager and kill the ruby process and delete the server.pid file in temp/pids

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because another server is really running - try running `localhost:3000` in your browser.

It doesn't need to be the same rails app - it is simply saying that port 3000 is already taken. You might:

1. Restart your machine
2. Run app on different port: `rails s -p 3001 #or other port`
3. Find what is taking port 3000 and kill it (you must be sure it is ok to kill it first though):

   `fuser -n tcp 3000     #=> 3000/tcp:        xxxx
    kill xxxx`

Answer (score 0):

Kill the already running instance by getting the pid through:

ps aux | grep rails

Then kill it