# Error running rails server, server already running

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to run rails server on the cmd I get an error saying:

```
A server is already running. Check C:/Users/owner/blog/tmp/pids/server.pid.
Exiting
```

Windows performed an update recently, and it was working fine before, I don't know if it has anything to do with that.  Server.pid says 4808.  When I check localhost:3000 It's certainly not running.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072846/server-is-already-running-in-rails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is self explainatory a server is already running for your app. *When you start your server rails creates server.pid file in your app and when you close your server this file is updated automatically. In your case you didn't close your server properly or by somehow this file isn't updated and hence your error.* ***Deleting your `tmp/pids/server.pid` file in your app will fix this issue for you***