# Can anyone figure out why I am seeing this error when trying to boot my React and Rails servers in Atom?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, reactjs, atom-editor

I followed the instructions here 
https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/how-to-get-create-react-app-to-work-with-your-rails-api/ 
to create a react app with a rails backend. Basically, I have the rails api proxied through localhost:3001, as specified here in package.json:

```
{
"name": "fidirect",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
"devDependencies": {
"enzyme": "2.4.1",
"react-addons-test-utils": "15.4.0",
"react-scripts": "0.8.5"
},
```

I have foreman in the gemfile, and a procfile that looks like this:

```
web: cd client && npm start
api: bundle exec rails s -p 3001
```

I have a rake task to handle booting both servers, in lib/tasks/start.rake, that looks like this:

```
task :start do
  exec 'foreman start -p 3000'
end
```

All of this is exactly as specified in the README for the sample app, but when I hit rake start, I see this error:

```
 started with pid 24179
 05:24:10 api.1  | started with pid 24180
 05:24:13 web.1  |
 05:24:13 web.1  | > fidirect@0.1.0 start /home/adt6261-
 133051/code/FiDirect/client
 05:24:13 web.1  | > react-scripts start
 05:24:13 web.1  |
 05:24:22 web.1  | Attempting to bind to HOST environment variable: 
 138.68.11.226
 05:24:22 web.1  | If this was unintentional, check that you haven't 
 mistakenly set it in your shell.
 05:24:22 web.1  | Learn more here: 
 05:24:22 web.1  |
 05:24:22 web.1  | Something is already running on port 3000.
 05:24:23 api.1  | => Booting Puma
 05:24:23 api.1  | => Rails 5.1.4 application starting in development
 05:24:23 api.1  | => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
 05:24:23 api.1  | Puma starting in single mode...
 05:24:23 api.1  | * Version 3.11.2 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Love Song
 05:24:23 api.1  | * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
 05:24:23 api.1  | * Environment: development
 05:24:23 api.1  | * Listening on tcp://138.68.11.226:3001
 05:24:23 api.1  | Use Ctrl-C to stop
 05:24:23 web.1  | exited with code 0
 05:24:23 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
 05:24:23 api.1  | - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
 05:24:23 api.1  | === puma shutdown: 2018-02-07 05:24:23 +0000 ===
 05:24:23 api.1  | - Goodbye!
 05:24:23 api.1  | Exiting
 05:24:23 api.1  | terminated by SIGTERM
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue before/ know what the problem might be? Any input greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your terminal run `lsof -wni tcp:3000` and you should be able to see the service running on that port, then `kill -9 <service number>`

An alternative is using a different port for y service

Comment: If this answer was solving your problem, you can find more info in the below link for deleting the running server. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072846/server-is-already-running-in-rails

Comment: This seems to be a linux command. Do you know an equivalent one that works on windows? I have tried netstat with various combinations, but non has worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have answered your own question.

Do you have any other apps that are running/using that port? I'd suggest maybe listing existing processes using `ps` and then spotting to see if there is another instance of your app running.

Nonetheless, best of luck!