# ROR + A server is already running. Check .../tmp/pids/server.pid. Exiting

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails Project, I am trying to run two different servers at different port. But it fails by giving this error at console.

```
C:\Rails>rails s
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 3.1.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
A server is already running. Check C:/Rails/tmp/pids/server.pid.Exiting
```

Please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

After googling a lot, I just delete that file and restart the server. Then again system create that file, then again I delete that file. Now Server is running fine. And System generates another copy at the same place. But it is running well.

```
DELETE THAT FILE ....
```

If you want to run two servers then it may again create trouble. So

Both commands are checking the default PID file location (tmp/pids/server.pid), so you're seeing this error. Try running multiple servers like so:

```
Server 1: bundle exec rails s

Server 2: bundle exec rails s -p 3001 -P tmp/pids/server2.pid
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14446920/1376448

Thanks

**UPDATE** after Connor Leech comment about Forman Gem

> Foreman can help manage multiple processes that your Rails app depends
>   upon when running in development. It also provides an export command
>   to move them into production.

Comment: Try using forman gem to run your app on multiple ports. Using foreman you can declare the various processes that are needed to run your application using a Procfile http://railscasts.com/episodes/281-foreman?view=comments

Comment: For what it's worth, Foreman seems to increase the amount of times I have to deal with this problem.

Comment: author himself asked, himself answered after googling a lot in 2 minutes ... =)

Comment: @MikhailMorgunov :- First of all, I tried at my end. After that I posted the question and answer for all dev. I dnt think - This will harm any one. Thanks for reminding, I made the updation in question.

Answer (score 38):

You can use netstat to know which process is holding the rails webserver, then you can kill the pid and start it over again, assuming that for some weird reason the server is not responding or running in background and you don't find another way to restart it..

```
netstat -plntu | grep 3000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7656/ruby
```

The last column shows the PID and the process name, then you only need to do:

```
kill -9 7656
```

and `rails s` to get it working again...

Hope it's useful

Comment: well in this case is not necessary but it shows udp connections and listening ports, depending on the other arguments..

Comment: If `netstat` doesn't work for you (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97212/netstat-n-unknown-or-uninstrumented-protocol) you can still find your `pid` number in your `server.pid` file, just copy that and kill in the same way.

Answer (score 17):

I find myself coming back to this webpage a lot to find the `lsof -wni tcp:3000` command so  I've found this method to be easier.

If you get this message:

```
A server is already running. Check /Users/username/project/tmp/pids/server.pid.
Exiting
```

And if you're running on a unix system (mac or linux) you can run these commands:

```
$ cat /Users/username/project/tmp/pids/server.pid

# output

71030

# Kill the process

$ kill -9 71030
```

Then run your server again!

Answer (score 15):

I deleted the file with cd'ing in to the tmp directory then removing the file

```
rm server.pid
```

Then I restarted the server and I got this error

```
Exiting/Users/josephmellin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/socket.rb:206:in `bind': Address already in use - bind(2) for 0.0.0.0:3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

Then I could use the following command to see which process is running.

```
sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P | grep :3000
```

And after I entered my password, I got this resoponse

```
ruby      2786 josephmellin   12u  IPv4 0xfeadd8ae849eaec9      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
```

And then killed the process with the following command

```
KILL -9 2786
```

And then restarted the server  (you will have a different number than 2786 - I left it here for demo purposes)

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: remove .pid

```
C:/Rails/tmp/pids/server.pid.Exiting

# IN linux/unix shell
$ rm -rf <path to file>
```

Sometime this doesn't solve the problem, then you have to kill the process running by localhost, for such cases, follow `STEP 2`

STEP 2: List the process for localhost and kill it

```
# For Linux/Unix shell

$ lsof -wni tcp:3000

# output
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    5946 rails   11u  IPv4  79073      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
ruby    5946 rails   12u  IPv4 103786      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3000->127.0.0.1:53612 (ESTABLISHED)

# Kill the running process
$ kill -9 5946
```

run your server again

```
rails server
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ps aux | grep rails
           or 
bundle exec rails s -p 3001 -P tmp/pids/server2.pid
```

Answer (score 2):

Every instance of a RoR server creates a PID file.  By default it is

```
#{Rails.root}/tmp/pids/server.pid
```

and if that file already exists it will refuse to start a new server.

To run more than one server of the same project on the same machine you should manually specify the PID file name for each instance of the server (I recommend simply appending a hyphen and the port number) using the `-P` option:

```
rails s -p 1234 -P tmp/pids/server-1234.pid
```

I'm told in some cases you may need to supply a full (rather than relative) path, but I don't know what those cases are.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the PID for each proccess(the first column) :

```
ps vax | grep rails
// OR:  ps auxw | grep rails

5236 pts/1    Sl+    1:46   2   0.2 /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 script/rails s -p 3001
5298 pts/2    Sl+    0:12   2   0.7 /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 script/rails s -p 3003
7356 pts/5    Sl+    0:09   2   0.9 /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 script/rails s -p 3002
7846 pts/3    Sl+    0:19   2   1.7 /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 script/rails s
```

Then kill the server:

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

To kill all running apps with "rails" in the name:

```
killall -9 rails
```

Answer (score 1):

Use rails default commands, for example:

```
rake tmp:clear
```

Works for me, and really simple. ;)

Comment: You should refer [this document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

single line command, that will take care of it.

```
kill -9 $(more C:/Rails/tmp/pids/server.pid)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem, just deleted server.pid file and server works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Remove that file: C:/Rails/tmp/pids/server.pid

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way in which I found lesser commands . Go to the path which says a server is running in your folder structure . Search for the file. On the file itself shows a number which is the process id that is currently running. Lets say if the number is 'x', then simply type this command into your terminal

```
kill -9 x
```

However, note that this works in Ubuntu. Not sure, if it works in other OS as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the number in the pid file to another and save it.