# Running many Rails server for Same application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, localhost, port, webrick

Is it possible to run same project or application in different port ? Suppose, I have project/application Blog, I want to run in this project at once in two different port. When I run server i.e `rails server` , then it run in port 3000. Again, in next terminal tap, I try to same project but in different port i.e `rails server -p 300`1 but it doesn't run ?

Is there any other way to run same project in different in different port at localhost sever ?

Comment: @RSB I think stackoverflow is not for revenge. Try to be more clear about it before you are doing anythings

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127412/ror-a-server-is-already-running-check-tmp-pids-server-pid-exiting

Comment: @Santosh But I have work on same project. IOS developer is working same project. So for them I have make my server running at localhost and I am working on it and I want to work in next port.

Comment: I tried helping you, you wrote `rails sever` instead of `rails server`, I had mentioned that in my answer, check the spelling in your question

Comment: @RSB check out the question below. Don't try to be over smart dude.

Comment: Yes I can see the edit, now it looks fine. Please go through this link, you will get to know how to ask a good question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 7):

Rails uses the pid of your running server to check whether a server is already running or not.

This is stored under tmp/pids/server.pid
If you want to run the same application again (why but?), you need a different pid for your server.

```
rails s -p 4000 --pid tmp/pids/server2.pid
```

Comment: I see a new comment below your question that shows a duplicate question. You should've searched stackoverflow extensively before giving bad attitude to people.