# When I stop a rails server via Ctrl+Z there is tedious work afterwards to get it up and running. Could there be a script to solve that for me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, ruby-on-rails-5

It would be nice for the script to be easy to add inside an alias on my .bash_profile so that I only hit `Ctrl + Z` and some alias and boom server up again without having to search manually on my text editor for the tmp/pids/server.pid and stopping that process and then removing the port id and then starting the server again. That for every time I need a forced stop.

**Edited:**

Based on some comments I'll clarify why I'm in this situation in the first place:
I use Ctrl+Z when I want to stop the server but I'm inside a binding.pry and don't want the rest of the process to run because it can lead to fill the DB with useless data which I will have to delete later. If you try stopping the server inside of the binding with the classic Ctrl+C it will never stop and hitting `exit` will lead to the process to continue.

Comment: I think that if you have to kill your server with Ctrl+Z instead of Ctrl+C, then 1) You need to find out why and fix that  2) you need to understand what Ctrl+Z actually does: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/135077/ctrl-c-vs-ctrl-z-with-foreground-job/135078

Comment: I use Ctrl+Z when I want to stop the server but I'm inside a binding.pry and don't want the rest of the process to run because it can lead to fill the DB with useless data which I will have to delete later. If you try stopping the server inside of the binding with the classic Ctrl+C it will never stop. If you have a suggestion I'm open to editing my question and my answer. In any case I do feel the script is helpful

Comment: In order to get out of binding.pry without continuing the programm, type either `exit` or `!!!`

Comment: @Clara - it might not be possible to type anything if he's using puma (rails default) as this would run in a sub process. However, if this is really such a pain, it is better just to switch to webrick in development. The script provided below is an equivalent of disposing of the body - it solves the problem that should not really exist.

Comment: Well, according to his answer he can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option A**

Based on Clara's comment an easier and cleaner way to do the stop is just to type `!!!`. That will give you a `SystemExit (exit)` from which you can just stop with the classic <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> and voilá!

**Option B**

If you still want that script anyway, based on findings from these questions [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088163/cant-stop-rails-server/41584419), [b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127412/ror-a-server-is-already-running-check-tmp-pids-server-pid-exiting/15127430) and a couple more like those, I summarized those answers into this script inside an alias to add to my .bash_profile.

```
alias fix_server="kill -9 $(touch tmp/pids/server.pid && cat tmp/pids/server.pid) && rm tmp/pids/server.pid && fg"
```

So now I just need to do <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> and `fix_server`.