# server is already running. Check C:/Rails/tmp/pids/server.pid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Every time when I run 2 rails server on different port say 3000 and 3001.

After starting server on port 3000

```
Rails$ rails s -p 3000 
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 3.1.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

when I run second rails server on port 3001,

```
Rails$ rails s -p 3001
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 3.1.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3001
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
A server is already running. Check /Rails/tmp/pids/server.pid.
Exiting
```

I need to delete server.pid file, before I am able to start rails server on port 3001.
Is there any way to avoid this deletion of file every time?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Start your consecutive applications like:

```
rails s -p 3001 -P tmp/pids/server_2.pid
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14446920/1376448

Comment: "-P tmp/pids/server_2.pid"  is only required for same application otherwise it is not necessary