# Relocate Rails /tmp/pids/server.pid file to system /tmp/pids/

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a proper way to relocate server pids from ~/[RAILS APP]/tmp/pids to the system /tmp/pids folder? The reason is to create functions to stop and restart rails server by a simple function. Or is there an alternative, preferable, approach?

Answer (score 3):

Try starting the server with this:

`bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -P [NOT RAILS]/tmp/pids/server.pid`

Credit: [Rails Update to 3.2.11 breaks running multiple servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329370/rails-update-to-3-2-11-breaks-running-multiple-servers/14446920#14446920)